# Accessing react i18next on nested components in different package

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, react-i18next

I'm trying to use the react-i18next library in a Next.js application, and I'm looking for the best way to access i18n instance inside child component that are inside a differen module.

I ll make an exmple to explain it better

_app.js

```js
import i18n from './i18n';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import Component from './Component';
import ComponentInDifferentPackage from 'different-package/src/Component';

const App = props => {
    return (
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <Component></Component>
            <ComponentInDifferentPackage></ComponentInDifferentPackage>
        </I18nextProvider>
    );
};
```

i18n

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        lng: 'en',
        backend: {
            /* translation file path */
            loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}.json'
        },
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        debug: false,
        keySeparator: false,
        react: {
            useSuspense: false
        },
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
            formatSeparator: ','
        }
    });

export default i18n;
```

Component

```js
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const Component = () => {
    // ** Hook
    const { i18n, t } = useTranslation();

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{t("title")}</h1> {/* this works */}
        </div>
    );
};
```

ComponentInDifferentPackage

```js
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const ComponentInDifferentPackage = () => {
    // ** Hook
    const { i18n, t } = useTranslation();

    // Here i18n is an empty object

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{t("title")}</h1> {/* this doesn't works */}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Now I'm passing the i18n as prop in the component like this

ComponentInDifferentPackage

```
const ComponentInDifferentPackage = (i18n, t) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{t("title")}</h1> {/* this works */}
        </div>
    );
};
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way without having to pass the istance down the all tree of components.

Thanks